PostgreSQL not using index on materialized view
I've got a materialized view which has 2 columns (patient_id BIGINT, department_ids TEXT[]).
It is a handy precomputed dataset used to filter patients who have received care in a hospital department in recent history. There is a unique index on the patient_id field and a GIN index on the department_ids field which should help array intersection queries like SELECT * FROM pat_mv WHERE department_ids && ARRAY['dept1', 'dept2']. There are around 30k rows in the MV.
However, PostgreSQL is refusing to use the indexes at all. I would expect that
SELECT patient_id FROM pat_mv WHERE patient_id = 1001 would perform an index scan, but instead it does a full sequential scan. This is causing issues when the MV is used in a more complex query, where PostgreSQL JOINs this MV using Nested Loops, and does a full scan in each loop. I'm not sure why it doesn't do a Hash Join, but I'd be content with Nested Loops, if the index actually worked.
Running ANALYZE on the MV didn't help. I've tried to reload the data into a regular table with indexes and that works, so the data size is large enough for indexes to be used, and the issue is specific to the materialized view. I get that rewriting the solution to use a table instead of MV is an obvious workaround, but it's not a trivial change, and I still wonder what's the catch here. Is it supposed to work in the first place? The PostgreSQL is version 14.

Did you explicitly add indexes to the materialized view? What is the output of EXPLAIN ANALYZE yourQuery;?

Yes, the indexes are created on the MV directly, as if it was a table. EXPLAIN showed me that they were not getting used.

Through trial and error, I have discovered that it's the UNIQUE index that is giving Postgres trouble. When the index on patient_id is defined as UNIQUE, the queries will not use it. However, when the index is recreated without the UNIQUE keyword, it works. But it's not that simple as "unique indexes don't work" – on my machine and on our development environment with test data, it works, on a client installation it doesn't… the Postgres versions are however identical, the installation is done using docker images.

try what happens if you set jit = off; before your query

I did that, and after that the index was getting used, but then it was getting used even after set jit = on; and I'm no longer able to reproduce the issue. This is getting weirder by the minute.
